# SSO from custom application to SharePoint 2013

Tags: single-sign-on, sharepoint-2013

We have a custom web application that authenticates against Active Directory. I need to provide single sign on from my application TO SharePoint 2013 site.

Can you suggest the available options ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPNEGO in your application. That works. Elaborate on your client in the question please.

Comment: Thanks for update.  one client is a .net custom application and other client is SharePoint 2010 (separate farm)  Note that all user computers are not logged into the same domain.

Comment: They do not have to be logged into to the same realm but you will require your admin to create at least an one-way cross-realm trust to authenticate clients from realm A to a the server which is in realm B.